# symfony + AJAX how to upload files embedded in javascript JSON objects?

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a client uploading files embedded in JSON objects because each one of these files has attached metadata.

The problem is that I do not know how many files they will upload so I need something dynamic

at the moment I have a `fileList` javascript object that contains sub objects that looks like this:

```
{
  file1: null
  meta1: null,
  meta2: null,
  etc...
}    
{
  file2: null
  meta1: null,
  meta2: null,
  etc...
}
```

I upload it like this:

`formData.append('files', this.fileList);`

but in symfony, I do not know how to process this particular situation

If I look in the profiler I get something like this :
`files  "[object Object],[object Object]"`

and `$files = $request->files->get('files');` gives `null`

Is there another way to decode the data? it is there but I can't read it :(

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: To a Symfony Form, that metadata is going to be field data, so I'd subtype with a `FormType` that has a `FileType` and each metadata field you need would be, say, a `TextType`. That would shadow the idea of what you're showing here, and use a collection to have (0,) 1, or more of that combination.

Comment: The `json` part would be your header `Content: application/json`. Then Symfony's `HttpFoundation` component will auto-parse it and put the `FileType`s together for you.

Comment: `$request->files()`, if that's an `HttpFoundation\Request`, is going to be the `$_FILES` array, so won't fit here.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't understand what you are suggesting; I changed from `multipart/form-data` to `Content: application/json` but nothing changed and I am not sure how linking a form type would help if I can't access the data ? I am not using symfony forms if that's why you suggested it. if I dump `$_FILES` I get nothing either

Comment: You should clarify your question. It's a bit confusing with all the references to `files` and `fileList`, it sure seems like you're wanting file data with accompanying field data, which a Symfony `FormType` can handle (it doesn't need a form frontent). In fact, I don't think you can have actual uploaded file content in a JSON body unless it's base 64-encoded, otherwise you have to `Content: multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Actually, hmm, if you have a file to upload, one per metadata row, I'd send the file separately with Ajax and pend it (with a cleanup script that deletes them when 24hr old, S3 does this nicely). Then return that path to the form, put that in your JSON-ified body you submit, then you have your metadata, which happens to include it's pending filepath. Move that pending file on submit and keep that new reference when you save the row or whatever. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file to upload, one per metadata row, I'd send the file separately when it's selected in the form (I like BlueImp for this, but there are others) with Ajax and pend it to a directory (with a cleanup script that deletes them when 24hr old, S3 does this nicely). Then return that path to the form, put that in your JSON-ified body you submit, then you have your metadata, which happens to include it's pending filepath. Move that pending file on submit and keep that new reference when you save the row or whatever. Voila.

So:

```
files[][filename].onchange: [/* Upload file to pending, return pending path */]
```

With return path, `pending/ad32sY3KJ.png`, submit

```
"files": [
    ["file":"`pending/ad32sY3KJ.png`","meta1":"Root Beer"],
    ["file":"`pending/34dks3DWf.png`","meta1":"Cat"]
]
```

Then your router handler has an array, so `Content-type: application/json` works as expected, although you'd use:

```
$body = \json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

Instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation; Im sure someone will implement it but I m not familiar with S3 and I was hoping to stay on my server. It seems weird to me that the data is there and I can't read it. If S3 does it then there must be a way to read this data within symfony.

Comment: There's no S3 requirement, I simply remarked that you can auto-expire pending files that never get moved in S3. A folder in your local server works just fine, with a cron script looking for old files will do the same thing.